# Ignoring NaNs with str.contains

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find rows that contain a string, like so:

```
DF[DF.col.str.contains("foo")]
```

However, this fails because some elements are NaN:

> ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

So I resort to the obfuscated

```
DF[DF.col.notnull()][DF.col.dropna().str.contains("foo")]
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 436, accepted):

There's a flag for that:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([["foo1"], ["foo2"], ["bar"], [np.nan]], columns=['a'])

In [12]: df.a.str.contains("foo")
Out[12]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3      NaN
Name: a, dtype: object

In [13]: df.a.str.contains("foo", na=False)
Out[13]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

See the [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) docs:

> na : default NaN, fill value for missing values.

---

So you can do the following:

```
In [21]: df.loc[df.a.str.contains("foo", na=False)]
Out[21]:
      a
0  foo1
1  foo2
```

Comment: Over here I had a situation where `a` was populated from a CSV, and the `a` column contained the string "nan".  `pandas` "intelligently" converted this to `NaN` and started complaining when I tried to do `df.a.str.contains()`.  So yeah protip: make sure to set the column type in `read_csv()` or afterwards do something like `df = df.where(pandas.notnull(df), "nan")` LOL

Comment: Why `df.loc` and not just `df`?

Comment: @PascalVKooten either is fine, ilike .loc since imo it's a little more explicit.

Comment: Ya saved me... if this wasn't here, i think i would of been through a nightmare of two weeks banging my head into the wall :-) definitely worth a +1, lol

Comment: Lol why isn't this default?

Comment: Bingo. This should be a default flag!

Comment: Wish other str functions offered `na` such as str.extract().

Comment: if not default, would be nice if the Erro message suggest to use na=False...

Answer (score 19):

In addition to the above answers, I would say for columns having no single word name, you may use:-

```
df[df['Product ID'].str.contains("foo") == True]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

```
df[df.col.str.contains("foo").fillna(False)]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `query` method to query the columns of a DataFrame with a boolean expression as follows:

```
df.query("a.str.contains('foo', na=False)")
```

Or more interestingly, which I think is more readable:

```
df.query("a.str.contains('foo')==True")
```

Note you might not get performance improvement, but it is more readable (arguably).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% on why (actually came here to search for the answer), but this also works, and doesn't require replacing all nan values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([["foo1"], ["foo2"], ["bar"], [np.nan]], columns=['a'])

newdf = df.loc[df['a'].str.contains('foo') == True]
```

Works with or without `.loc`.

I have no idea why this works, as I understand it when you're indexing with brackets pandas evaluates whatever's inside the bracket as either `True` or `False`. I can't tell why making the phrase inside the brackets 'extra boolean' has any effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also patern :

```
DF[DF.col.str.contains(pat = '(foo)', regex = True) ]
```