# ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Tags: python, excel, string, csv

I do not understand why I am receiving the error listed in the title, the value that I am intending to return is the number 30

```
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\khalha\\Desktop\\RealExcel')
filename = 'sales.csv'

Sales = pd.read_csv('sales.csv')
iFlowStatus = Sales[Sales['Product'].str.contains('iFlow')]['Status']
print(iFlowStatus)
```

Comment: @MoxieBall I am new to python and am not ever able to find a good site that explains errors in details. Would you happen to know of one?

Comment: My above comment is a link to a stack overflow answer you should read

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignoring NaNs with str.contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311655/ignoring-nans-with-str-contains)

Comment: @MoxieBall yeah but that problem is not the same issue as mine, I have all the values present in the csv file but it is still giving me this error

Comment: if it is giving you that error, it means that there are NA/ NaN values

Comment: @MoxieBall in the exact cell i am trying to extract the value from, the value is 30. However, throughout the excel file, there are blank spaces. But that exact cell is not a blank space. Do you think the blank spaces in the rest of the file is contributing to this?

Comment: Yes, that error will occur if `contains` is used on any vector that contains NaNs and does not use the solutions linked above.

Comment: @MoxieBall Okay thank you, that got rid of that error, however another one appears now, i changed my line to this:
iFlowStatus = Sales.loc[Sales['Product'].str.contains('iFlow', na=False)]['Status']
    
  pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Factory'

Comment: @MoxieBall the KeyError should say Status actually, I was just testing around different headers

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The error message means that the dataframe contains blank entries that default to na/NaN.

You can just add `na=False` in the synatx to fill value for missing values.

```py
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\khalha\\Desktop\\RealExcel')
filename = 'sales.csv'

Sales = pd.read_csv('sales.csv')
iFlowStatus = Sales[Sales['Product'].str.contains('iFlow', na=False)]['Status']
print(iFlowStatus)
```

Comment: No problem, yes I had figured it out about a month ago, but it is good for the benefit of anyone who sees this post, so thanks!

Answer (score 11):

One other possible issue: you can get this with mixed-type columns that do not contain NaN. For example:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['hi', 99]})
> df.x.isna().any()
False
> df[df.x.str.contains('hi')]
...
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values
```

Depending on what you want to do, you can cast (`df.x.astype(str).str.contains('hi')`) or drop the offending rows.

Comment: Thankyou @Kristina, I was facing same problem. I had removed all nan but was still getting this issue.

Comment: I like this solution better because it makes clear that the root of the problem is attempting to perform string operations on non-string values, which is not easily inferable from the error message.