# filtering rows in Pandas with specific words (python)

Tags: python, pandas

```
mask = df['command'].str.contains('<')   
df[mask]
```

I am using the command above to filter out the rows in which its `command` column contains `<`. This gives me:

```
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values
```

Any help?

Comment: you can do `df.fillna('any_value', inplace=True)` and then run it

Comment: You mean before running `df[mask]`? It gives me the same error

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311655/ignoring-nans-with-str-contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
mask = df.fillna('')['command'].str.contains('<')
```

or as @Vaishali [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311655/ignoring-nans-with-str-contains)

```
mask = df['command'].str.contains('<', na=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `na=False`:

```
df['command'].str.contains('<', na=False)
```

Otherwise, areas where `df.command.isnull()` return `np.nan` instead of `False`, as one would expect.