# Word - List Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

Here`s my dataframe

```
    drug        reaction     
0   OMALIZUMAB  Forced expiratory volume decreased  
1   OMALIZUMAB  Upper limb fracture 
2   OMALIZUMAB  Blood pressure abnormal 
3   OMALIZUMAB  Forced expiratory volume decreased  
4   OMALIZUMAB  Anxiety 
5   OMALIZUMAB  Asthma  
6   OMALIZUMAB  Fall    
7   NITROGLYCERIN   Product substitution issue  
8   OMALIZUMAB  Patella fracture    
9   OMALIZUMAB  Anxiety
```

What I want is to dictionary the reaction of the drug.
There are several reaction for a drug.

so output what I want is

```
{drug : [reaction], drug: [reaction], ...}
```

Example is only part of dataframe, and real data is bigger than ex.(600,000rows)

How can I get the result I want?

Comment: what dictionary? drug_dt? drug_ct? could you explain or show a sample of your final output?

Comment: @sammywemmy drug_dt! /  drug_ct is for counting.. I first try to this so I have no output about this

Comment: if you dont mind, could you explain what u r trying to achieve? it is possible that we can get the results you want without the iterations. if possible could you generate a to_dict of ur original dataframe and post

Comment: @sammywemmy I edit my question more clearly.. can you check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use defaultdict, with a list option to group the items based on the keys. 

 In this case the keys are from the drug column

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(list)
```

Use a list comprehension to make it faster

```
[d[i].append(j) for i,j in zip(df.drug, df.reaction)]

print(d)

defaultdict(list,
        {'OMALIZUMAB': ['Forced expiratory volume decreased',
          'Upper limb fracture',
          'Blood pressure abnormal',
          'Forced expiratory volume decreased',
          'Anxiety',
          'Asthma',
          'Fall',
          'Patella fracture',
          'Anxiety'],
         'NITROGLYCERIN': ['Product substitution issue']})
```

Comment: My server got some problem.. I`ll try later and let you know the result!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe answers in this issue can work for you too;

[Ignoring NaNs with str.contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311655/ignoring-nans-with-str-contains)

You can try the command below referencing to Harry_pb's answer.

```
df[df['dr.prod_ai'].str.contains("foo") == True]
```