# Pandas Numpy np.where handling of nulls

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a np.where statement in my python script which assigns the new column values based on a search within another column, looks like this:

```
df['campaignNameFilter'] = pd.np.where(df['campaignLabels'].str.contains("Core Brand", case=False), "Core Brand",
pd.np.where(df['campaignLabels'].str.contains("Product Ranges", case=False), "Product Ranges",
pd.np.where(df['campaignLabels'].str.contains("Product Types", case=False), "Product Types",
pd.np.where(df['campaignLabels'].str.contains("Other", case=False), "Other",
pd.np.where(df['campaignLabels'].str.contains("Sports", case=False), "Sports",
pd.np.where(df['campaignLabels'].str.contains("Brand Expanded", case=False), "Brand Expanded",
pd.np.where(df['campaignLabels'].str.contains("Non-Brand", case=False), "Non-Brand",
pd.np.where(df['campaignLabels'].str.contains("Brand", case=False), "Brand",
pd.np.where(df['campaignLabels'].str.contains("Sub-Brand", case=False), "Sub-Brand",
pd.np.where(df['campaignLabels'].str.contains("Product ID", case=False), "Product ID",
pd.np.where(df['campaignLabels'].str.contains("All Products", case=False), "All Products",
pd.np.where(df['campaignLabels'].str.contains("Showcase", case=False), "Showcase", "NOT ASSIGNED"))))))))))))
```

So, it will go through the 'campaignLabels' column and assign the values to a new column called 'campaignNameFilter'. Now, if it does not find anything that matches, the 'campaignNameFilter' will be assigned as NOT ASSIGNED.

It all works great, however, the issue is when the campaignLabels column is null, it automatically assigns it as the first statement so in this case, it would be "Core Brand". Is this an error in Numpy/Pandas or is this the expected behavior?

I am using Pandas 0.24.2 and Numpy 1.16.3.
Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you need `na=False` parameter? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311655/ignoring-nans-with-str-contains)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `numpy.where()`, I'd advise using `numpy.select()` when dealing with multiple options and if none match, and else result. You need to set conditions and results met in order:

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [df['campaignLabels'].str.contains("Core Brand", case=False),
             df['campaignLabels'].str.contains("Product Ranges", case=False),
             df['campaignLabels'].str.contains("Product Types", case=False),
             df['campaignLabels'].str.contains("Other", case=False),
             # ... you get the idea
             ]

results = ["Core Brand",
           "Product Ranges",
           "Product Types",
           "Other",
           # ... you get the idea
          ]

else_result = "NOT ASSIGNED"

df['campaignNameFilter'] = np.select(conditions, results, else_result)
```