# Pandas: How do I search series cells for partial string match?

Tags: python, pandas, string, series

I have a DataFrame created by importing an Excel sheet that has several columns but inconsistent text data in its rows.  For example, one column labeled "Airplane 1" has a "Gross weight: 2500" in row 25 where as the column "Airplane 2" has "Gross weight: 3000" in a different row.  All the columns have an entry for "Gross weight:" but their row numbers are off by 1 or more.  I can iterate through the columns and rows, but I can't seem to query a cell in a row for a specific string.  I've tried several approaches, below find one fail.  It's reasonably clear that I'm erroneously trying to generate a single boolean from series, thus generating the error, but I can't seem to get into the separate cells in the series.  Ultimately, I want to identify specific parameters, "Gross weight:" for example, extract and tie the number associated with that parameter with its specific column.  And yes, I'm new at this, thanks in advance...

Just to show that the data is there...

```
#print(df.at[2,'Aviat_A-1B'])
x = df.loc[11,"Aviat_A-1B"]
#x.partition(':')
#print(type(x))
#print(x.split(':'))
print(x)

Gross weight (lbs.): 2000
```

This doesn't work...

```
sub = 'Gross weight (lbs.):'
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(type(index))
    print(index)
    print('~~~~~~')
    print(type(row))
    print(row)
    print('------')
    if row.str.extract(sub):
        print(type(row))
        print(row)
        print('------')


<class 'int'>
3
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
1997_7GCAA_American_Champion_Adventure                              Price as tested: $76,000
Aviat_A-1B                                                       Engine make/model: Lycoming
1960_Beech_Travel_Air_B95                                     Engine make/model: Lycoming...
1979_Beechcraft_Bonanza_A-36                                                        IO-520BB
1977_Bellanca_8KCAB-180_Super_Decathlon                       Engine make/model: Lycoming...
                                                                 ...                        
1974_Piper_Arrow_II_with_LoPresti_Speed       Price: $48,500 (plus mod. cost)               
1999_Piper_Archer_III                              Engine make/model: Lycoming              
Ryan_Navion                                       Engine make/model: Cont. E-185            
1997_Mooney_Ovation                              Engine make/model: Continental IO-550G     
1997_Mooney_Encore_Prototype                   Engine make/model: Cont TSIO-360-SB          
Name: 3, Length: 61, dtype: object
------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-8590ea2a7401> in <module>
     11     print(row)
     12     print('------')
---> 13     if row.str.extract(sub):
     14         print(type(row))
     15         print(row)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1327 
   1328     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1329         raise ValueError(
   1330             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1331             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
UPDATE
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

There has to be a smarter way than this to find and extract a number, 199 in the case below...

`wing_area = []
#print(df)
for col, item in df.iteritems():
#    print(col)
    wing_area_bool = item.str.contains("Wing area", na=False)
#    print(df.index[wing_area_bool])
#    print(item[wing_area_bool])

#    wing_area.append(item[wing_area_bool])
#    wing_area.append(item[wing_area_bool].str.split(":"))
    wing_area.append(item[wing_area_bool].str.split())
    
print(wing_area[-1])
#print(len(wing_area[-1]))
#print(str(wing_area[-1]))
#x = (str(wing_area[-1]).split(","))
#y = x[-2].split("]")
#int(y[0].strip())
int(str(wing_area[-1]).split(",")[-2].split("]")[0].strip())

22    [Wing, area, (sq., ft.):, 199]
Name: 1960_Beech_Travel_Air_B95, dtype: object
199`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df.column_name.str.contains("Gross weight", na=False)]
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311655/ignoring-nans-with-str-contains)

To do this iteratively you could loop over the column names when doing this

```
for name in [column_name_1, column_name_2, column_name_x]:
     df.loc[df.name.str.contains("Gross weight", na=False)]
```

And depending on what youd like to do with the result you would do it in the loop

Comment: Not quite - I imported the .xls file using ```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file = 'C:/Light AC data.xls'
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=0)
df.dropna(inplace = True)
df```           (Sorry, I don't know how to enter indented code in the reply...).  That may be why, when I use your suggestion (which I had tried in a slightly different manner - I have 61 columns which I want to iterate through) I got this...
df[df["Aviat_A-1B"].str.contains("Gross Weight")]...
ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values...

Comment: Try df.loc[df.a.str.contains("Gross weight", na=False)]  [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311655/ignoring-nans-with-str-contains)

Comment: That did it, thanks!  Now I just need to figure out how to do this iteratively through all the columns.  Oh, and thanks for the reference pointer!

Comment: Great! See my updated answer for performing this on each column

Comment: Actually, I adapted your recomendation
wing_area = []

for col, item in df.iteritems():
    wing_area_bool = item.str.contains("Wing area", na=False)
    wing_area.append(item[wing_area_bool].str.split(":"))
    
print(type(wing_area))

print(wing_area[0])

<class 'list'>
22    [                   Wing area (sq. ft.),  165]
Name: 1997_7GCAA_American_Champion_Adventure, dtype: object

Comment: Which gives me the proper row and data for the first column, 
but now I can't seem to extract the number (165 in this case)

Combinations of wing_area[0:-1], wing_area[0][-1], etc. result in the error
"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"

Comment: Lastly, how do you enter code like you've done above?  When I Ctrl K I get popped out to a browser search.

Comment: Because I don't know how to show code in the comment section I added a very ugly way to get to what I ultimately want (a number, from a specific row, that varies across the columns).  See above starting with "There's got to be a smarter...."  TIA,  dj