# Filter a dataframe column for a keyword, return seperate column value (name) from the row where each keyword is found

Tags: python, string, dataframe, filter

if a have a data frame and I want to return the values in one column if I find a keyword in another. So below if I search for `apple` I want the output to be `[a,b]`

like this:

```
names words
a     apple
b     apple
c     pear
```

I would want a list that is:
`[a,b]`

I have found ways to return the boolean value using `str.contains`, but not sure how to take the value from another column in the same row which will give me the name. There must be a post I cant find if anyone can direct me there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
list(df[df['words'].str.contains('apple', na=False)]['names'])
```

resulting in

```
['a', 'b']
```

1. `df['words'].str.contains('apple', na=False)` build a boolean pandas series for the condition, and taking care of eventual missing values in the column.
2. the  series resulting from previous line is used filter the original dataframe df.
3. in the dataframe resulting from previous line, the 'names' column is selected.
4. in the dataframe resulting from previous line, the column is cas to a list.

Full code:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
data = """
names words
a     apple
b     apple
c     pear
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

lst = list(df[df['words'].str.contains('apple')]['names'])


>>>print(lst)

['a', 'b']
```

Comment: thanks I get an error that says. `Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values`. found this page [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311655/ignoring-nans-with-str-contains] but still not clear. The column datatypes are objects with heavy text if that helps?

Comment: @Gazoo, how can we answer if you do not provide date pertaining to your problem?

Comment: @hpchavez oh I added this and it worked: `str.contains('apple',case=False, na=False)`

Comment: You probably have some rows with missing values in the `'word'` column: as   `na=False` provides a return for missing values.  `case=False` is irrelevant. is irrelevant.

Comment: @hpchavez I never assumed, NA would throw it off since I only need those that have "apple" , although I wrongly assumed there were no NAs as well!! I was getting this error before on a few attempts and I thought it was my code! THANKS!!!!